# install4j error on Mac OS X

Tags: install4j

I am using install4j to create a Window and Mac OSX installer for a new version of my software. The only thing that has changed since my last distribution is my application. I have not changed any of the launcher or media file options in install4j. After building the installer, the Windows installer runs fine. The Mac OSX installer gives an error message on some machines. The message is "You need at least a 1.7 Java Virtual Machine to install..." However, a user reported that they already have 1.7 installed but still gets the error message. Does anyone know what is causing this error? Does install4j require 1.7 to run on a Mac?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit the media file of your Mac OS X installer and go to the "JRE" step. If "Installed OpenJDK JRE" is selected, then Java 7 and higher is required. The above message indicates that no such JRE was installed. Also, make sure to update to the latest version of install4j.